# Using pickled python class through java runtime

Tags: java, python, scikit-learn, pickle

I built a binary SVM classifier from some strings using scikit-learn:

```
count_vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=10, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 4))
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts)
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', tol=1e-3)
clf.fit(X_tfidf, Y)
```

Then I created a wrapper class around the trained classifier and pickled it:

```
class Classifier:
    def __init__(self, clf, vect):
        self.classifier = clf
        self.vectorizer = vect

    def classify(self, s):
        return self.classifier.predict(self.vectorizer.transform([s]))[0]

with open('my_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fout:
    pickle.dump(Classifier(clf, count_vect), fout)
```

In a separate script, I can load the pickled classifier and use it properly:

```
with open('my_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
    clf = pickle.load(fin)

result = clf.classify(sys.argv[1])
print(result)
```

However, when I try to execute the script through java Runtime, it shows incorrect output.

```
public boolean classify(String s) throws IOException {
        String cmd = "python3 pkl_classifier.py \"" + s + "\"";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String out = stdIn.readLine();
        if (out != null) {
            switch (Integer.parseInt(out)) {
                case 0: return false;
                case 1: return true;
                default: throw new RuntimeException("Error with classifier script:" + out);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The output of the classifier can be 0 or 1. But this java code always produces a 0. I have printed out the entire command (`cmd`) from java and executed it directly in terminal and it produced correct output. But the output produced by java Runtime is always 0.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You sure you should use `getInputStream` but not `getOutputStream`?

Comment: Yes. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) says getInputStream "returns the input stream connected to the normal output of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the standard output of the process represented by this Process object."

Comment: Well, I think you are right. My fault:) How about try printing `out` to debug?

Comment: I did. I just omitted the debug prints in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the problem.

It was in the script I was executing through java.

Let's say the string I want to classify is `"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"`. When I formed the command to classify it in my java class as

`String cmd = "python3 pkl_classifier.py \"" + s + "\"";`

it appeared as

`python3 pkl_classifier.py "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"`

which is exactly the command I wanted to execute. When I printed out the variable `cmd`, it appeared okay. But when I printed the command in the python script using

`print(sys.argv)`

it appeared as

`['pkl_classifier.py', '"lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet"']`

So apparently it was splitting the command by whitespaces ignoring the quotes.

Then I changed the script from

`result = clf.classify(sys.argv[1])`

to

`result = clf.classify(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))`

it worked just fine!

**Better solution:**

Instead of tweaking the python script, it's better to use the other `exec()` method of `Process` class that takes the arguments as an array of strings. It will take care of the whitespaces inside the arguments internally.

```
String[] cmd = { "python3", "pkl_classifier.py", s };
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```